# Angular2/4 Dom single time update only.

Tags: angular, dom, meteor, angular2-template, angular-meteor

I am working on a `Angular-4` and `Meteor` application and I am having this problem since I started the application that `Dom` or `HTML` is not updating. For Example: `Meteor.user()` wants some time to find the user and show its detail or etc. 
So if I have some date from `Meteor.user().fullName` and when I load the page, getting errors like

> full name is not defined and etc.

So I have used `NgZone` for it, but using `NgZone` too many times makes my application heavy and loaded. 
So how can I concise my code by using a good `Angular-2/4` feature?
If you know any better please tell.